# Is there a way to break out of #omp parallel

Tags: c++, openmp

I've got a situation where I have two `#pragma omp task`s inside a `#pragma omp parallel` block

The first task is a simple job of just waiting 5 seconds.  The second task has the more difficult job of waiting for a complex user input action.

```
bool timed_out=false;
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(2), shared(timed_out)
{
  #pragma omp task
  {
    sleep(5);
    #pragma omp atomic write
    time_out=true;
  }
  #pragma omp task
  {
    // wait for user input
  }
  #pragma omp taskwait
}
```

Basically, what I'd like to happen as either after the user input is received successfully or the 5 second time out is hit then I'd like to break out of the `#pragma omp parallel` section and continue with main.

I don't think I can use `#pragma omp single` after my taskwait because if the user input is received the next thing that would occur is the spawning of two worker threads.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please note that your initial example does not generate two tasks, but four, as each of the two OpenMP threads in the parallel region will encounter the `task` construct and thus create a task.  You would have to wrap the two `task` constructs with a `master` or `single` construct to avoid this and ensure that only one task creates tasks:

```
bool timed_out=false;
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(2), shared(timed_out)
{
  #pragma omp master
  {
    #pragma omp task
    {
      sleep(5);
      #pragma omp atomic write
      time_out=true;
    }
    #pragma omp task
    {
      // wait for user input
    }
    #pragma omp taskwait
  }
}
```

For the termination of the waiting, second task, you can use OpenMP cancellation:

```
bool timed_out=false;
#pragma omp parallel master num_threads(2), shared(timed_out)
{
  #pragma omp taskgroup
  {
    #pragma omp task
    {
      sleep(5);
      #pragma omp atomic write
      time_out=true;
      #pragma omp cancel taskgroup
    }
    #pragma omp task
    {
      while(true) {
        #pragma omp taskyield
        #pragma omp cancellation point taskgroup
      }
    }
    #pragma omp taskwait
}
```

The `taskgroup` is needed to define the tasks that should be affected by `cancel` construct.  The `cancellation point` construct in the waiting task will terminate the `while` loop once the `cancel` construct was encountered.  As the second task is spin-waiting it contains a `taskyield` to introduce a task scheduling point and permit the OpenMP implementation to schedule another task (this is not needed for your minimal example tough, but might be useful for a code with more OpenMP tasks).

Comment: I just recognized that I reversed the roles of the tasks, but I guess that the point still comes across.